# I cannot install Matrix Rates Package on my Magento website

Tags: installation, package

I keep getting 
Cannot find command package-prepare 
when I click install 
I am running 1.9.2

Comment: have you  install zip file via backend?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Please provide more information: Which extension are you talking about? What were the exact steps you have taken?

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Comment: can you help me regard Matrix rate https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/241323/39050 @teja

Comment: @Rathinam is product ids 4, 5 contain in single category or in multiple categories ?

Comment: Single category, like category id 4 consists plastics products and category id  5 consists metals products @Baby

Comment: @Rathinam by default, is webshop matrix supports entering product ids in excel sheet ?

Comment: No, input data like https://i.stack.imgur.com/xONab.png

Comment: just asking, shell i write sql code like if category id 4,5 the delivery is not India Post

Comment: than for my knowledge , its not possible..... you may need to do some customization for that module or try by some other way.....

Comment: @Rathinam you can write, but take backup before doing any changes....

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82867/matrix-rate-custom-condition